# Cannot create record for associated model in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a record for the associated model in rails console in the form `Contact.first.to_do_items.create!()` and I have `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Validation failed: contact must exist`

Models:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :to_do_items
end

class ToDoItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :сontact
end
```

It works well when I'm using `optional: true` in the `ToDoItem` class but I'm curious why it's not creating a record with the code listed above.

Comment: By default, any `belongs_to` will throw an error if the association isn't set. That's why it works with `optional: true`. You just need to create the `Contact` first before you create their `ToDoItem`s

Comment: @Jon yeah, but with `Contact.first` I definitely have `Contact`, no?

Comment: Not necessarily. Does `Contact.first` actually return a contact?

Comment: @Jon sure, I have more than one `Contact' in my database :)

Comment: Try it in multiple steps then. `contact = Contact.first` then `todo = contact.to_do_items.build` then `todo.save` and check if it saved, if not, check `todo.errors`